# Chat simulator in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat, sendto

What I am trying to do is basically simulate a client-server-client chat using threads. Here is the code so far:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time
from random import randint

clients = []
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8000

class Server():
    def __init__(self):        
        self.addr = (HOST,PORT)
        global clients

        self.start()
        for i in range(5): Thread(target=self.clientHandler).start()

        self.s.close()

    def clientHandler(self): 
        conn, addr = self.s.accept() 
        clients.append(addr)

        print addr[1], "is Connected" 
        while 1: 
            time.sleep(5)

            # message=repr(data)
            # message=message[1:-1].split(':')
            message='test'                               #for debug
            conn.sendto(message, clients[1])             #for debug
            # conn.sendto(message[1], clients[int(message[0])])

    def start(self):    
        self.s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        self.s.listen(5)

        print "Server is running......"


class Client(threading.Thread):
    global clients
    def sendMessage(self):
        if len(clients)>1:
                to=randint(0, len(clients)-1)
                message = str(to)+':hello from '+self.name
                print message
                self.ss.send(message)

    def receiveMessage(self):        
        while 1:
            reply=self.ss.recv(1024)
            if reply != '':
                print self.name+" received ", repr(reply)
                break

    def run(self):    
        self.ss = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ss.connect((HOST, PORT)) # client-side, connects to a host
        self.name=self.ss.getsockname()[1]

        while True: 
            # time.sleep(randint(1,5))
            # self.sendMessage()
            self.receiveMessage()

server=Server()
client1=Client()
client2=Client()
client3=Client()

client1.start()
client2.start()
client3.start()
```

The idea is that one client should send a message to another random one (have not considered excluding itself yet) over and over again. To do so, the message has the format `dest: message`, where `dest` is a random index for choosing a client from the `clients` list.

After hours of "debugging", I discovered that the sendto() method sends the message to all the clients, not just the one with the specified address (as the above code does). Am I using it wrong?

Also, when I make the clients send messages, they just receive the message right back. What am I doing wrong?

I know it is messy, and sorry about that. I just started working with Python and I am testing multiple methods to see how they work.

Thank you. - Python Noob

Comment: Two things come to my mind:  1. are you aware that threads can communicate using `Queue`?  There's no need to use sockets for this.  Sockets are for interprocess communication but you only have one process (with several threads).  2. You should reduce the problem you are facing to a minimal size still showing the problem.  It seems to me there's a lot of code and ideas in your post which are not necessary to understand (e. g. the clientHandler threads _and_ the clients which are threads).  This makes it complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works since the second argument to [`sendto`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man2/send.2.html) is ignored for TCP sockets.

For your idea to work, you must actually read something on the server. But first, let's look at the other obvious problems:

You are creating exactly 5 threads on the server. This is not harmful yet, but may be in the future. Instead, just create a thread when needed, as in

```
class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()
        self.addr = (HOST,PORT)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        self.s.listen(5)
        print "Server is running......"

        while True:
            conn, addr = self.s.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=self.clientHandler, args=(conn, addr)).start()
```

Then, don't store the address, store the socket:

```
def clientHandler(self, conn, addr):
    clients.append(conn)
```

Furthermore, in `clientHandler`, read from the sockets:

```
def clientHandler(self, conn, addr):
    clients.append(conn)
    while True:
         msg = read_from_socket(conn)
         id_str, _, msg = msg.partition(b':')
         clients[int(id_str.decode('ascii'))].sendall(msg)
```

`read_from_socket` must be a function that reads your message format. Since TCP is packet-less (imagine it as one infinite stream, until the remote end closes), you must define a message format. Let's do that now, by waiting for the newline `b'\n'`:

```
def read_from_socket(conn):
    buf = bytearray(0)
    while True:
        b = conn.recv(1)
        buf.extend(b)
        if b == b'\n':
             return bytes(buf)
```

Then we simply have to adapt the client to add a `\n` byte:

```
class Client(threading.Thread):
    def sendMessage(self):
        if len(clients)>1:
                to = randint(0, len(clients) - 1)
                message = ('%s:hello from %s\n' % (to, self.name)).encode('utf-8')
                print(message)
                self.ss.send(message)
```

Finally, make sure to actually send a message (at the moment, you don't):

```
server=Server()
client1=Client()
client2=Client()
client3=Client()

client1.start()
client2.start()
client3.start()

time.sleep(1)
client1.sendMessage()
```

[Here is the entire code](https://gist.github.com/phihag/8350691).